# Electrical Single Phase Transformer

Tags: transformer

I am helping my 6th grade son on science project on Single Phase Transformer - I need Hypothesis and a brief outline of this. Where can I obtain this information?

Comment: Are guidelines provided? Is this a literature research project or an experimental project. Is a transformer provided? Do know what has been taught about transformers?

Comment: This is very vague. What's the project exactly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a basic research question with zero effort, and no request for at least clarification of information.

Comment: You don't "obtain" hypotheses, you make them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Although these Transformers have the ability to change form fit and functions, electrical power transformers can only transform power by changing the ratio of voltage and current such that the V*I out is the same or less than the input power V*I.  Where V is alternating sinewave voltage and Imis the alternating current determined by the type of load.

The hypothesis is that the input power is equal to the output power needed plus a small percentage of internal losses.

The mechanics of this transformation is like a lever arm where you can have the same force times distance or output swing  and a pivot point to determine the ratio. The internal magnetic induction Forces are called Electromagnetic forces.

The pivot point is the turns ratio where 1:1 is like the middle of a teeter totter with balanced f=ma like a transformer Vin*Iin=Vout*Iout is balanced + <5-10% internal conduction losses